# IYO: worst subversion misfeatures?

Tags: svn

what are in your opinion the worst subversion (and subversion/cvs style tools) misfeatures and what feature you would expect/wish to use and are not there?

thanks :)

edit, i forgot to mention them,
for me the major lacking features are:
- cannot erase what have been done previously; monotonicity helps a lot the implementation but having to delete a password would mean dumping the repo, editing the file by hand, reloading the repo (it's not a specific svn fault, though)
- metadata is here, but not really usable. i think it's not possible to interpolate custom properties, efficiently search using the tags, ...
- the client is a bit too free; it's hard to enforce client behavioural costraintsby the administrators.
- crypto authentication of peers (though, https or ssh tunneling help at networking level)
- merge-style operations with a mandatory central repo seems neither fish nor flesh for me: either full centralization and strict control or full decentralization and support for offline ops convinces me more.

i have to clarify that i'm not particularly against svn, it has a *lot* of good points, but good points are not useful as starting point for future improvements ;)

Comment: Voting to close as subjective and argumentative.

Answer (score 8):

What I don't like with subversion is that it requires `.svn` subdirectories in the working copy.

Comment: This results in very high costs in terms of file-system operations required for typical workspace manipulations. This is particularly a problem under Windows as the file system is suboptimal and often further impeded by a virus scanner.

Comment: i wholeheartedly agree especially on this one. i actually had huge problems committing due to an antivirus interferring with tsvncache, and in any case the idea of interleaving data and metadata causes a lot of problems. e.g. git does this much better (one .git dir only in the root dir, and you can place it elsewhere with a bit of customization).

Comment: +1 this also causes countless issues with users corrupting their working copy by moving folders around. Having only one .svn folder in the root of the working copy would eliminate most of the pain caused by this

Answer (score 1):

Calling the merge range start and range end FROM and TO, which always leads people to think it means merge changes FROM somewhere TO merge target, when it actually means merge changes that happened between FROM and TO and apply them to the *working copy*.

That, and making merges a pain in all sorts of other ways, too.

Comment: Yup, I've had to clear up just this misunderstanding a number of times.